# MySQL Query Retrieve Tags in TWO Categories (AND not OR) [WordPress Raw SQL]

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Struggling with this for a while

```
   SELECT DISTINCT terms2.term_id as tag_id, terms2.name as tag_name, terms2.slug as tag_slug, t2.description as tag_desc
    FROM
        wp_posts as p1
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r1 ON p1.ID = r1.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t1 ON r1.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms1 ON t1.term_id = terms1.term_id,

        wp_posts as p2
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r2 ON p2.ID = r2.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t2 ON r2.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms2 ON t2.term_id = terms2.term_id
    WHERE
    t1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id IN (224,229) AND
    t2.taxonomy = 'product_tag' AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p1.ID = p2.ID
    ORDER by tag_name
```

Line I am dealing with is this one:

`t1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id IN (224,229) AND`

This works, but the `IN` clause acts as an `OR`--- so it is bringing back tags that are in either the `term_id` `224` or `229`

I am trying to make it so that it only returns tags that are in BOTH `224` and `229`

I've tried

`t1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id = '224' AND
 t1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id = '229' AND`

but it just returns an empty result...

The only solution I have right now is to do two queries `terms1.term_id = '224'` for `224` and terms1.term_id = '229' for `229` and then use other logic to return the two matching.

Is there a way to combine this into one query?

Edit: See results of the IN query below (modified so that `terms1.term_id` is visible)

[image]

As you can see `Gray` is only in 229 (and thus not part of the result set I am trying to return back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BrianBruman I'm assuming that `terms1.term_id` is a comma separated list of values. If this is the case, you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` to make sure both `224` and `229` are in the comma delimited list.

Here is what your query needs to look like in order to get tags with both `224` and `229`:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT terms2.term_id as tag_id, 
      terms2.name as tag_name, 
      terms2.slug as tag_slug, 
      t2.description as tag_desc
  FROM
      wp_posts as p1
      LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r1 ON p1.ID = r1.object_ID
      LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t1 ON r1.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id
      LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms1 ON t1.term_id = terms1.term_id
      JOIN wp_posts as p2 ON p2.ID = p1.ID
      LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r2 ON p2.ID = r2.object_ID
      LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t2 ON r2.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id
      LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms2 ON t2.term_id = terms2.term_id
    WHERE
      t1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' 
      AND p1.post_status = 'publish' 
      AND (
              FIND_IN_SET('224', terms1.term_id) > 0 
              AND FIND_IN_SET('229', terms1.term_id) > 0
          )
      AND t2.taxonomy = 'product_tag' 
      AND p2.post_status = 'publish'         
    ORDER by tag_name
```

EDIT: according to your last comment, `terms1.term_id` isn't a comma delimited list. In that case, you would need to join in another instance of `wp_terms`. Here is what your query needs to look like:

```
      SELECT DISTINCT terms2.term_id as tag_id, 
          terms2.name as tag_name, 
          terms2.slug as tag_slug, 
          t2.description as tag_desc
      FROM
          wp_posts as p1
          LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r1 ON p1.ID = r1.object_ID
          LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t1 ON r1.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id
          LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms1 ON t1.term_id = terms1.term_id
          LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms3 ON t1.term_id = terms3.term_id
          JOIN wp_posts as p2 ON p2.ID = p1.ID
          LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r2 ON p2.ID = r2.object_ID
          LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t2 ON r2.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id
          LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms2 ON t2.term_id = terms2.term_id
        WHERE
          t1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' 
          AND p1.post_status = 'publish' 
          AND terms1.term_id = '224' 
          AND terms3.term_id = '229'
          AND t2.taxonomy = 'product_tag' 
          AND p2.post_status = 'publish'         
        ORDER by tag_name
```

One last thing: if you only want results to show where `wp_posts` has a corresponding `wp_terms` record where the `term_id` is both `224` and `229` you shouldn't be using `LEFT JOIN` on `wp_terms`, you should use a regular old `JOIN`, which will improve the performance of your query a lot.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's cool, didn't know about `FIND_IN_SET`... but no, `term_id` is not a comma separated value... it is its each individual row.  I edited the main question with a photo as an example.

Comment: @BrianBruman I'd double check my 2nd query in my answer, after looking at it it might not work. You might also have to add another instance of `wp_posts` into the query in order for it to work 100%: you would join the extra `wp_posts` as `p3` to `terms3` the same way you join it to `terms1` and you would also have to add this to the where clause: `p3.ID <> p1.ID`. let me know if you still need help getting this to work and i'll revise my answer some more.